# Google Forms embedded iFrame is showing different language when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form embedded on a [wordpress.org site](http://geoparkcorumbatai.com.br/publicacoes/formulario-de-cadastro-de-pontos/) using an iFrame.

The code I'm using is:

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdNU2bOyHaWD9YupFcq1gGXfOMwku3l38O0MIaqx9aQ9IXUpA/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="4000" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Carregando…</iframe>
```

My Google Account and my original file are in Portuguese and it shows so when I open the website using Firefox. However when using Chrome, it shows the "layout text" in English.
Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your accept-language set to in each case?

Comment: Chrome is set to pt (portuguese) and Firefox to en